# Trying to use an assert command in conjuntion with arraylist using selenium, but it breaks if the elements are not in the proper order

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I have a string that needs to be compared to the names that are on the website. So the first thing I do is get the number of rows (because some arrays have more or fewer than 2 people in them) and then put that size into an int. `String[]` names come from the names that selenium is *supposed* to find when it goes to the website to execute this statement `assertTrue(assertion.getText().contains(names[i-1]));` The problem is: if the names do not appear in the order in which they appear in the array it breaks. In other words, if Mick Jagger is in `li[1]` and Keith Richards is in `li[2]`, everything runs as expected. But if Keith Richards appears in `li[1]` it breaks. Furthermore, I am supposed to use the assertTrue command to do this. I have tried sorting, pushing whats on the web into a new ArrayList and I keep getting errors. Anyone know a good way to ensure the order isn't important and still use the assertTrue command?

Thanks,
Scott

```
    WebElement assertion = null;
    List<WebElement> assignees = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='assignee']/li"));
    int count = assignees.size();
    String[] names = {"Mick", "Keith"};
    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
    {
    assertion = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='assignee']/li["+i+"]"));

    assertTrue(assertion.getText().contains(names[i-1]));
```

Comment: You could use [findElements](http://static.javadoc.io/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/2.52.0/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-) to get all assignees in one `List`, sort both the list and your expectation and compare them that way. Or just compare them if your expectation already contains the expected sorting order.

Comment: Would that still make use of "assertTrue?"

Comment: `assertTrue` takes a `boolean`. Checking for collection equality can easily resolve into a `boolean` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `names` represents the full string, you can just flip it. Make sure the text in your `assertion` (probably should  be named something like assignee instead of assertion) is contained in your collection:

```
assertTrue(Arrays.asList(names).contains(assertion.getText());
```

Let me know if this won't work because a `name` is actually a subset of the text in assertion and I'll adjust the answer.

---

If they don't exactly match (which you have indicated they don't), you could use **linq** in c# to match this. Since you're using **java** you can use an additional loop. There may be a more efficient way to do this in **java** that I'm not aware of.

```
String assigneeText = assertion.getText();
boolean nameFound = false;
for(String name: names)
{
    nameFound = assigneeText.contains(name);

    if(nameFound)
    {
        break;
    }
}

assertTrue(nameFound, "None of the expected names were found in the following assignee text: " + assigneeText);
```

Comment: Sorry I am really trying to format this properly and its not cooperating!!!                                                                                                           I did get an assertion error....

WebElement assigneeNames = null;
List<WebElement> assignees = driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='assignee']/li"));
int count = assignees.size();
Collections.sort(assignees);
String[] names = {"Mick", "Karen Keith"};
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++)
{
 assigneeNames = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='assignee']/li["+i+"]"));
 assertTrue(Arrays.asList(names).contains(assign

Comment: It sounds like the strings must not exactly match. So you might be comparing `Mick` to `Mick ` with a space or last name or something. The approach would be different in that case. Although do you know if it's just spaces that are the issue?

Comment: Yes it doesn't match exactly.... it also conatins each person's login name which I don't want to have to find out.

Comment: OK looking at this, I see why it doesn't work.  names must be contained in assertion, not the other way around

Comment: In c# you could use a linq expression for this, in java you can use an inner loop. See my updated answer.

Comment: Glad to hear! Feel free to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkbox. I've updated my answer as well to make the assertion error message more meaningful.